# how to put user input in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I'm trying to make an application in Java, and I want to put user input into an array. So a user has to fill in their grades like this:

```
System.out.println("Voer je FYS cijfer in:");



  double FYS = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Voer je user interaction cijfer in:");
    double userInteraction = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Voer je programming cijfer in:");
    double programming = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Voer je database cijfer");
    double databases = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Voer OOP 1 cijfer in:");
    double oop = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Voer je Personal Skills cijfer in:");
    double personalSkills = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Voer je Project skills cijfer in:");
    double projectSkills = input.nextDouble();
```

I want to put all those doubles into this array:

```
        double [] vakCijfers = new double [7];
        vakCijfers [0] =  0;
        vakCijfers [1] =  0;
        vakCijfers [2] =  0;
        vakCijfers [3] =  0;
        vakCijfers [4] =  0;
        vakCijfers [5] =  0;
        vakCijfers [6] =  0;
```

Iknow I have to do something with a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vakCijfers.length; i ++) {

        }
```

But what do I put into the for loop?
How can I actually put those inputs into the array?

Comment: If all inputs are  `System.out.println` then `input.nextDouble()` then you could put your questions in an array too. Then the loop becomes 'print question i from questions array', 'store input i in vakCijfers array'. But this feels wrong: wouldn't it make more sense to store each value by name in a structure?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < vakCijfers.length; i ++) {
vakCijfers[i]=input.nextDouble();
        }

Comment: But if constructing the array from named variables is the problem, you can just (I think) do `double[] vakCijfers = new double[] { userInteraction, programming, databases, ... }` to build a new array with the values you have already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get input from keyboard to fill the values to do that.

1- Use a Scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
double D = scan.nextDouble()
```

2- Use a BufferedReader with InputStreamReader.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

double D = Double.parseDouble();
```

your Solution will be like

```
for(int i = 0; i < vakCijfers.length; i ++) {
    system.out.print("Enter number vakCijfers " + i + " : ");
    vakCijfers[i] = scan.nextDouble();
}
```

read further https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/basic-input-output#javainput

Comment: The code OP posted has `input.nextDouble()`, so I'd guess they already have a Scanner?

Comment: Perhaps consider editing your link to official Java doc sources.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to put all theese zeros into your array- double has value of 0 by default.

Secondly if you're not obligated to use an array you can use List instead- it enables adding values to it via add(Object) method(Eventually you can always retrieve an array from a List calling toArray() if needed). Just replace all `double userInteraction = input.nextDouble();` with `someListInstance.add(input.nextDouble());`.

If you have to use an array all you have to do is take an input from user in for-loop and add it to the array's **i** index like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vakCijfers.length; i ++) {
vakCijfers[i] = input.nextDouble()
//some println if needed
        }
```

Comment: That kinda works but I want to print a different message every input? How do I do that in that loop?

Comment: You can have an array of Strings containing all determined messages. Then in for-loop you just take it via it's index and print it.
 
There is also a better approach. Create a class like one below:
`class MyDouble{
private double myDouble;
private String myMessage;
}`
and store an array of it. Then iterate on that array, and in every loop just print out myMessage and set myDouble.